# Why should I use CSS3 buttons?

Tags: client, css, css-sprites, fallback

I built a website recently, and decided to create buttons that depress on click with CSS3, pretty cool.

But is there really a valid reason to use CSS3 over a sprite, as only the modern browsers show the CSS3 buttons?

The client asked me this question, and all I could think of was less http requests, so loading would be slightly faster. I can see from a clients point of view that this is a pretty week answer.

Is there a better reason?

Or is there a fallback method that would be able to move a sprites background-position, or change the gradient and add a box shadow on a hover / focus?

Just writing that made me wonder if modernizer would be up to the challenge...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is much more a ethical and business question than a tech question, but let's see some points.

First, I think your client should not get to know all tech details about implementation. He/she should know what he/she needs to know, and that's enough.

You shouldn't say "I'll make your site with CSS3, some new HTML5 elements, and nice javascript eye-candy effects" for a non-tech folk. Just say "I can make a good site for you."

If he question about what your are using or why your think this is a best approach, then you reply with benefits.

It is lightweight, brings less problems with compatibility, and is easier to maintain. => Reduce time his/her client will be waiting to website load, everytbody can see it, and will cost less in the future requirements.

CSS3 is not a new revolutionary stuff, you should face these technologies are evolutionary. All previous rules still apply, including fallback rules.

CSS Sprites are a technique made with CSS2, thus it should work with any browser, including some old ones (not sure about IE6).

Gradients are new. FF 3.5+, IE9 beta, Opera and webkit browsers display them. IE8 or older don't. Some thing for box-shadows.

For these, I just added some really simple rules as fallback.

When I develop, I put the link to main stylesheet on page's header, and then I use a IE conditional comment for load IE only stylesheets and scripts.

On this IE only stylesheet, I just add the hacks or fallbacks needed to make it a little decent. You have MS filters to handle that. My IE.css stylesheet look like:

```
.gradient {
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#E6E6E6', endColorstr='#fff');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#E6E6E6', endColorstr='#fff')";
}

.boxShadow {
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#666666, direction=135, strength=5);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#666666, direction=135, strength=5)";
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666
}
```

Note that there are fallbacks rules even with these, to handle IE6, IE7 and IE8+. But it's tiny and ensure a better display.

Beside this I suggest you to read http://24ways.org/2009/ignorance-is-bliss

Modernizr is a good lib, but think if you really need it. You may be end using a bulldozer instead of a spoon.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dave. I agree with you, that I'm telling too much to the client, which would eradicate the problem in the first place. The MS filter code is very helpful though! Thanks for your time - appreciated!

Comment: Hi Joe. Nice to hear that my tips were helpful. Feel free to touch base directly with me if you have any other questions regarding CSS3, HTML5 and Microformats.